# Remove focus from SWF after mouse out

Tags: javascript, flash, focus

How Do I remove the focus from a swf using javascript? Now I use jQuery and I can set the focus but using blur does not work on a swf.

--EDIT--

Only Firefox and IE seems to get Focus in Chrome & Opera not

```
$("#ebookContainer").hover(
  function () {
    this.onmousewheel = function(){            
        return false
    };
    $('#ebook').focus();
  },
  function () {
    this.onmousewheel = function() {            
        return true;
    }
    $('#ebook').blur();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try document.body.focus() and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Thanks I tried but does not work.. I have also tried to to trigger('click') on body or other element but not work too...

To add it does work correct in Firefox but no IE & Chrome